# Thread Wait For Parent

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, pthreads, mutex

I am implementing a simple thread pool mechanism for my ubuntu server (for my multi-client anonymous chat program), and I need to make my worker threads sleep until a job (in the form of a function pointer and parameter) needs to be performed.

My current system is going out the window. I'm(the worker thread is) asking the manager if a job is available, and if there isn't sleep for 5ms. If there is, add the job to the working queue and run through the function. Wretched waste of cycles.

What I'd *like* to do is make a simple event-like system. I'm thinking about having a vector of mutexes (one for each worker) and have the handle to the mutex passed in as a parameter at creation. Then in my manager class (which holds and hands out jobs), whenever a thread is created, lock the mutex. When a job needs to be performed unlock a the next mutex in line, wait for it to be locked and unlocked, and relock it. However I'm wondering if there's a much better means to this end.

---

**tldr;** So my question is this. What is the most efficient, effective, and safest way to make a thread wait for a job from a managing class? Is polling a technique I should even consider (more than 1000 clients at a time), is mutex locking decent? Or are there other techniques?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is the condition variable.
All the worker threads call wait() which will suspend them.

The parent thread then puts a work item on a queue and calls signal on the condition variable. This will wake one thread that is sleeping. It can remove the job from the queue execute the job then call wait on the condition variable to go back to sleep.

Try:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <memory>
#include <list>

// Use RAII to do the lock/unlock
struct MutexLock
{
    MutexLock(pthread_mutex_t& m) : mutex(m)    { pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); }
    ~MutexLock()                                { pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); }
    private:
        pthread_mutex_t&    mutex;
};

// The base class of all work we want to do.
struct Job
{
    virtual void doWork()  = 0;
};

// pthreads is a C library the call back must be a C function.
extern "C" void* threadPoolThreadStart(void*);

// The very basre minimal part of a thread pool
// It does not create the workers. You need to create the work threads
// then make them call workerStart(). I leave that as an exercise for you.
class ThreadPool
{

    public:
         ThreadPool(unsigned int threadCount=1);
        ~ThreadPool();

        void addWork(std::auto_ptr<Job> job);
    private:

        friend void* threadPoolThreadStart(void*);
        void workerStart();

        std::auto_ptr<Job>  getJob();

        bool                finished;   // Threads will re-wait while this is true.
        pthread_mutex_t     mutex;      // A lock so that we can sequence accesses.
        pthread_cond_t      cond;       // The condition variable that is used to hold worker threads.
        std::list<Job*>     workQueue;  // A queue of jobs.
        std::vector<pthread_t>threads;
};

// Create the thread pool
ThreadPool::ThreadPool(int unsigned threadCount)
    : finished(false)
    , threads(threadCount)
{
    // If we fail creating either pthread object than throw a fit.
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) != 0)
    {   throw int(1);
    }

    if (pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL) != 0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
        throw int(2);
    }
    for(unsigned int loop=0; loop < threadCount;++loop)
    {
       if (pthread_create(threads[loop], NULL, threadPoolThreadStart, this) != 0)
       {
            // One thread failed: clean up
            for(unsigned int kill = loop -1; kill < loop /*unsigned will wrap*/;--kill)
            {
                pthread_kill(threads[kill], 9);
            }
            throw int(3);
       }
    }
}

// Cleanup any left overs.
// Note. This does not deal with worker threads.
//       You need to add a method to flush all worker threads
//       out of this pobject before you let the destructor destroy it.
ThreadPool::~ThreadPool()
{
    finished = true;
    for(std::vector<pthread_t>::iterator loop = threads.begin();loop != threads.end(); ++loop)
    {
        // Send enough signals to free all threads.
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    }
    for(std::vector<pthread_t>::iterator loop = threads.begin();loop != threads.end(); ++loop)
    {
        // Wait for all threads to exit (they will as finished is true and
        //                               we sent enough signals to make sure
        //                               they are running).
        void*  result;
        pthread_join(*loop, &result);
    }
    // Destroy the pthread objects.
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

    // Delete all re-maining jobs.
    // Notice how we took ownership of the jobs.
    for(std::list<Job*>::const_iterator loop = workQueue.begin(); loop != workQueue.end();++loop)
    {
        delete *loop;
    }
}

// Add a new job to the queue
// Signal the condition variable. This will flush a waiting worker
// otherwise the job will wait for a worker to finish processing its current job.
void ThreadPool::addWork(std::auto_ptr<Job> job)
{
    MutexLock  lock(mutex);

    workQueue.push_back(job.release());
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
}

// Start a thread.
// Make sure no exceptions escape as that is bad.
void* threadPoolThreadStart(void* data)
{
    ThreadPool* pool = reinterpret_cast<ThreadPool*>(workerStart);
    try
    {
        pool->workerStart();
    }
    catch(...){}
    return NULL;
}

// This is the main worker loop.
void ThreadPool::workerStart()
{
    while(!finished)
    {
        std::auto_ptr<Job>    job    = getJob();
        if (job.get() != NULL)
        {
            job->doWork();
        }
    }
}

// The workers come here to get a job.
// If there are non in the queue they are suspended waiting on cond
// until a new job is added above.
std::auto_ptr<Job> ThreadPool::getJob()
{
    MutexLock  lock(mutex);

    while((workQueue.empty()) && (!finished))
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        // The wait releases the mutex lock and suspends the thread (until a signal).
        // When a thread wakes up it is help until it can acquire the mutex so when we
        // get here the mutex is again locked.
        //
        // Note: You must use while() here. This is because of the situation.
        //   Two workers:  Worker A processing job A.
        //                 Worker B suspended on condition variable.
        //   Parent adds a new job and calls signal.
        //   This wakes up thread B. But it is possible for Worker A to finish its
        //   work and lock the mutex before the Worker B is released from the above call.
        //
        //   If that happens then Worker A will see that the queue is not empty
        //   and grab the work item in the queue and start processing. Worker B will
        //   then lock the mutext and proceed here. If the above is not a while then
        //   it would try and remove an item from an empty queue. With a while it sees
        //   that the queue is empty and re-suspends on the condition variable above.
    }
    std::auto_ptr<Job>  result;
    if (!finished)
    {    result.reset(workQueue.front());
         workQueue.pop_front();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The condition variable being a mutex/semaphore?

Comment: @ultifinitus: No. A condition variable is the lowest level primitive (along with mutex) in threaded code. You build semaphores from mutex/condition variables.

Comment: Haha thank you! I appreciate the help! I enjoyed the `I leave that as an exercise for you` part. I'll let you know how the end product ends up working.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way this is implemented is to have a queue `queue` of outstanding work, a mutex `mutex` protecting the queue, and a wait condition `queue_not_empty`. Then, each worker thread does the following (using pseudo-api):

```
while (true) {
    Work * work = 0;
    mutex.lock();
    while ( queue.empty() )
       if ( !queue_not_empty.wait( &mutex, timeout ) )
           return; // timeout - exit the worker thread
    work = queue.front();
    queue.pop_front();
    mutex.unlock();
    work->perform();
}
```

The `wait( &mutex, timeout )` call blocks until either the wait condition is signaled, or the call times out. The `mutex` passed is atomically unlocked inside `wait()`, and locked again before returning from the call, to provide a consistent view of the queue to all participants. `timeout` would be chosen rather large (seconds), and would lead to the thread exiting (the thread pool would start new ones if more work came in).

Meanwhile, the thread pool's work insertion function does this:

```
Work * work = ...;
mutex.lock();
queue.push_back( work );
if ( worker.empty() )
    start_a_new_worker();
queue_not_empty.wake_one();
mutex.unlock();
```

Comment: That's just what I was thinking, Thank you for the timeout, I had thought I would need to implement some sort of die job.. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Classical producer-consumer synchronization with multiple consumers (the worker threads consume work requests). The well-known technique is to have a semaphore, each worker thread does `down()` and each time you have a work request, do `up()`. Than pick the request from mutex-locked workqueue. Since one `up()` will only wake up one `down()`, there will actually be minimal contention on the mutex.

Alternatively you can do the same with conditional variable, doing wait in each thread and wake up one when you have job. The queue itself still locked with mutex (condvar requires one anyway).

Last I am not completely sure, but I actually think you can actually use a pipe as the queue including all synchronization (the worker threads simply trying to "read(sizeof(request))"). A bit hacky, but leads to fewer context switches.

Comment: Semaphore is the simple solution. It is usually implemented as a mutex a condition variable and a integer count. But in addition you must make sure that you control thread access to any other shared resource (like the list of pending work requests).

Comment: @Martin: I described both ways and did explicitly say the queue has to be locked. Due to the equivalence of synchronization primitives, the choice depends on which is more efficient in given environment. In fact this just implements message queue, so when one is available, just use it (the three equivalent synchronization primitives are semaphore, conditional variable and message queue).

Answer (score 2):

Since a network chat program is presumably I/O-bound rather than CPU-bound, you don't really need threads.  You can handle all your I/O in a single thread using a facility such as [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) or the [GLib main loop](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html).  These are portable abstractions over platform-specific functions that allow a program to block waiting for activity on *any* of a (potentially large) set of open files or sockets, and then wake up and respond promptly when activity occurs.

Comment: I've been doing everything on a single thread select() and poll(), I had just worried about speed... There isn't any need at all?

Comment: @ultifinitus, unless your program does a lot of CPU work (such as cryptography for SSL on each connected socket), it probably spends most of its time sitting idle waiting for input from clients, and uses the CPU for only brief intervals when input arrives.  There's no benefit in distributing a workload like that among multiple cores.

Comment: @Wyzard: That's fantastic! Should I have a backup system(multithreaded), do you think? If what you say is true, I'm **done**!!!

Comment: @ultifinitus, if you have it working already using `select()` or the like, I'd say stress-test it with a bunch of clients and take a look at the actual CPU usage.  If there are significant portions of time where the CPU is the bottleneck, then consider rewriting it to use threads.  If not, leave it as-is and avoid all the code complexity associated with threads and synchronization.

Comment: Found that without thread pools I can handle around 1600 clients (albeit active) at a time. I'll let you know about the thread pools when the implementation is done.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is `semaphores`. This is how a semaphore works:

A semaphore is basically a variable that takes null/positive values. Processes can interact with it in two ways: increase, or decrease the semaphore.

**Increasing the semaphore adds 1 to this magical variable**, and that's about it. **It's in decreasing the count that things get interesting**: if the count reaches zero and a process tries to lower it again, since it can't take negative values, it will **block until the variable rises**.

If multiple processes block are waiting to decrease the semaphore value, only one is woken up for each unit the count is increased.

This makes very easy to create a worker/task system: your manager process queues tasks and increases the value of the semaphore to match remaining items, and your worker processes try to decrease the count and acquire a task constantly. When no tasks are available, they'll block, and consume no cpu-time. When one appears, only one of the dormant processes will awake. Insta-sync magic.

Unfortunately, at least in the Unix world, the semaphore API is not very friendly, since for some reason it deals with arrays of sempahores rather than individual ones. But, you're a simple wrapper away from a nice interface!

Cheers!

Comment: That's nearly perfect! I'll definitely do some heavy research, thank you for the response!