# c++ pthread limit number of thread

Tags: c++, numbers, pthreads, limits

I tried to use pthread to do some task faster. I have thousands files (in args) to process and i want to create just a small number of thread many times.
Here's my code :

```
void callThread(){
    int nbt = 0;
    pthread_t *vp = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*NBTHREAD);
    for(int i=0;i<args.size();i+=NBTHREAD){
        for(int j=0;j<NBTHREAD;j++){
              if(i+j<args.size()){
                   pthread_create(&vp[j],NULL,calcul,&args[i+j]);   
                   nbt++;
              }
        }
        for(int k=0;k<nbt;k++){
              if(pthread_join(vp[k], NULL)){
                   cout<<"ERROR pthread_join()"<<endl;
              } 
        }
   }
}
```

It returns error, i don't know if it's a good way to solve my problem. All the resources are in args (vector of struct) and are independants.
Thanks for help.

Comment: **It returns error**. What is "it" and what error does "it" return?

Comment: what are you hoping to accomplish with thousands of threads?

Comment: A better idea would be to create a small pool of threads that act on jobs in a queue. Then add all the files to the queue and let the threads pick the jobs off one by one until there is no more work to be done.

Comment: I don't want thousands of threads, i just want to apply the function "calcul" on every struct in "args". But thoose struct are independant so i want to speed up process.

Comment: @LokiAstari i don't know pool of thread but i think this is what i'm looking for. I will try whit it

Comment: does it work with a small number of threads? If so you might be reaching the limit for the number of processes that you can run. You can check what that is with `ulimit -u`.

Comment: It just means start a small fixed number of threads (this is called a pool). Then the threads run a function that is basically a loop where the thread checks to see if there is work. If not it sleeps. If there is work it takes it executes the work and then returns to the pool of available threads. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5799978/14065

Answer (score 3):

You're better off making a thread pool with as many threads as the number of cores the cpu has. Then feed the tasks to this pool and let it do its job. You should take a look at [this blog post right here](http://progsch.net/wordpress/?p=81) for a great example of how to go about creating such thread pool.

A couple of tips that are not mentioned in that post:

- Use `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` to get the number of cores.
- Figure out a way how to store the tasks, hint: `std::packaged_task` or something along
  those lines wrapped in a class so you can track things such as when a task is done, or implement `task.join()`.
- Also, github with the code of his implementation plus some extra stuff such as `std::future` support can be found [here](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a semaphore to limit the number of parallel threads, here is a pseudo code:

```
Semaphore S = MAX_THREADS_AT_A_TIME  //  Initial semaphore value
declare handle_array[NUM_ITERS];

for(i=0 to NUM_ITERS)
{
wait-while(S<=0);
Acquire-Semaphore;  //  S--

handle_array[i] = Run-Thread(MyThread);

}

for(i=0 to NUM_ITERS)
{
Join_thread(handle_array[i])
Close_handle(handle_array[i])
}


MyThread()
{
mutex.lock

critical-section

mutex.unlock

release-semaphore // S++
}
```